# HTTPS requests getting aborted after 2 seconds

Tags: google-app-engine

We have a deployed java application on GAE. We have enabled SNI SSL certificates. For the last few days, we have observed that that any HTTPS request that are taking more than 2 seconds are getting aborted by server (as reported by browser). This is consistently happening on FF, IE and Chrome on Windows XP, Windows 7 64bit & Safari and Chrome on Mac Mountain lion. The error that is shown on Chrome is "Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data", where in IE (v9.0) is throwing error 12152.

This was consistently reproduced by hitting a URL, mapped to a java servlet, which is made to sleep for >=2000 ms. The sleep interval was given as a request parameter and tried with varied value of 1000 to 5000 ms. The above mentioned error was thrown for all values >=1900 ms, while any thing less than that would not yield any issues.
However, there were no issues faced if the URL scheme is changed to HTTP.

GAE application logs did not show any error or any signs of new instance spawning off. We are App engine version 1.8.1 and java version is 6.

Any ideas to solve the issue would be immensely helpful.

Edit: The issue is only there for custom domains. It works fine for appspot domain. (xxxxx.appspot.com)

Sreejith

Answer (score 0):

That error is widely known and is related to your internet cache (see [the bug report for Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=84313), for example).

After a quick search, everybody seem to agree that these solutions *could* fix the problem

- clear your browsers cache (maybe use some external programs)
- reset your browsers preferences to the default ones
- uninstall and install again your browsers

Some other people suggest to perform a system restore, but that seems too extreme to me.

Comment: The time limit that I specified is in milliseconds and not in seconds. The issue is that the request is getting aborted after 2 seconds

Comment: Whoa, totally sorry about that. I guess I didn't properly read the question.